# How to refresh spotify token

Tags: php, api, spotify

Since spotify's token expires in one hour, I'm looking for a way to get a new token.

The following code can't do it.

Can anyone spot an issue with my code?

```
<?php
function get_token(){
    $url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
    $fieldString = "";
    $ClientID     = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $ClientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $headers = array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($ClientID.":".$ClientSecret)
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($response);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $json->access_token;
}

get_token();
```

Comment: After you make this call to get an access token you should also get a refresh token. An OAuth refresh token has a much longer lifetime than an access token and can be used to re-authorize your access and make subsequent calls.

Comment: @tshimkus What is "refresh token"? How can it be issued or confirmed? And where should I put the "refresh token" in the code above?

Comment: I could not find how long the Spotify refresh token lasts so I don't know the best way to approach this. I have worked with OAuth systems where the refresh token lasts 60 days, and its expiry gets refreshed each time the API gets called, so it is essentially immortal. In these cases I have stored it in a global variable in my code since it's not going away.

Comment: If it has a shorter lifespan you can treat it more like a session variable I suppose. Could you modify your code here with by adding `var_dump($json);` inside the function before the return so I can see what the refresh token expiration is?

Comment: FYI, there is a fairly comprehensive PHP wrapper for the API on GitHub: [jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php). I suggest you take a look at this module's [session.php](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/blob/master/src/Session.php), which includes functions to get and refresh access tokens. You could either deploy this package on your site or use it as a reference to establish an OAuth flow and refresh tokens.